# Strapi находится в рабочем режиме, редактирование типов контента отключено

Tags: strapi

Столкнулся с проблемой, хочу создать новые типы/компоненты в Content-Type Builder в админке Strapi. Однако получаю сообщение:
"Strapi находится в рабочем режиме, редактирование типов контента отключено. Пожалуйста, переключитесь в режим разработки, запустив сервер с помощью Strapi Developer."
Логичная ошибка и решение кажется тоже логичным - перейти в режим разработки.
Я изменяю URL в config/server.js c "продовского" на localhost и запускаю `yarn develop`.
После чего получаю табличку в консоле, где Title, Process PID и т.д. и Environment | development, и собственно ссылку на админку localhost:1337/admin. При этом редактирование и создание новых типов так же не доступно по той же ошибке.

Папку с проектом перенес с сервера к себе для локального запуска.

На сервере продолжает работать prod.

Версия strapi v4.10.6, node v16.13.0

Запуск develop происходит через команду `yarn develop`, прода через `pm2 start 'NODE_ENV=production yarn start'`.

При сохранении какого-то файла dev-сервер перезапускается.

Пробовал делать перебилд, не помог, хотя он и не должен влиять на development